# How to make new javascript object from object using string as key for new object

Tags: javascript, json

I know this should be very basic , but I am struggling to find answer , spent 5 minutes figuring out how to compose  title for this question :)

```
var response = [{id:1 , name:"Some Name"} , {id:2 , name :"Other Name"}]
var prefixResponse = "users";
var newResponse = {prefixResponse : response }
```

This will not work as you know , what I need is that newResponse should look like

`{users:[{id:1 , name:"Some Name"} , {id:2 , name :"Other Name"}]}`

Is this possible to achieve without using JSON striginfy than converting back to JSON

I know it is simple but coming from PHP this is trouble for me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bracket notation for variables:

```
var newResponse = {};
newResponse[prefixResponse] = response
```

Comment: Thanks, i knew it was simple !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bracket notation:

```
var newResponse = {};
newResponse[prefixResponse] = response;
```